# Getting TFS dashboard widget ID with REST API call

Tags: javascript, rest, tfs, widget, dashboard

I want to get the id of a widget, because I need to pass it to a web service when the user saves the configuration. [I have found out, there is a REST API service for this.](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/dashboard/widgets)
If I enter the following URL in my browser (substituting specific info in the brackets of course):

```
https://{account}.VisualStudio.com/DefaultCollection/{project}/{teamId}/_apis/dashboard/dashboards/{dashboardId}/widgets/{id}?api-version={version}
```

it works fine, however I get an HTTP 401 (Unauthorized) error when I try to make an ajax get request from the javascript code of the widget.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which authentication type do you use in your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a personal access token and use it in your code.

Useful articles:

- https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/team-services/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate
- https://www.visualstudio.com/nl-nl/docs/integrate/get-started/rest/basics

Answer (score 0):

401 HTTP status means that you either are not authenticated with the API or are not authorized to perform a particular operation. TFS Rest API from what I can see allows two types of authentication:

- [Basic](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/auth/overview)
- [OAuth](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/auth/oauth)

The documentation of the API at https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/overview explains it quite well and provides CURL commandline examples. Go and have a look.